# System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: handler

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, ajaxcontroltoolkit

First of all guys, dont vote it down. I have searched stackoverflow thoroughly for this question but couldnt find one.

I am receiving this exception from live application. It is too generic to post my code for it. If someone asks to post my code on the page, I will post that too.

The error was logged and I have no idea how to reproduce it.

```
System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: handler
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptComponentDescriptor.AddEvent(String name, String handler)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.DescribeComponent(Object instance, ScriptComponentDescriptor descriptor, IUrlResolutionService urlResolver, IControlResolver controlResolver)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.RenderScriptAttributes(ScriptBehaviorDescriptor descriptor)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.GetScriptDescriptors(Control targetControl)
   at System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl.System.Web.UI.IExtenderControl.GetScriptDescriptors(Control targetControl)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptControlManager.RegisterScriptDescriptors(IExtenderControl extenderControl)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScriptDescriptors(IExtenderControl extenderControl)
   at System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at ASP.candidateresume_aspx.__RenderContent5(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Adding the code surpasses the character limit of a question. I dont think something is wrong in the code. This is a very generic exception.

The code is uploaded on Google Docs

[Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_LJ7JfgiyasbjhVMEFHbWY4TGc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share here code block so can be identified what is problematic

Comment: I am so sorry krish but I am not able to add the code, as it surpasses the allowed character limit.

Comment: Check for empty value of client events in AjaxControlToolkit controls (e.g. `OnClientPopulated=""`)

Comment: Sure, let me find if there is any.

Comment: whoever has voted it down please share the reason for doing so

Answer (score -4):

The error is clear

System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: handler
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptComponentDescriptor.AddEvent(String name, String handler)

The problem is that the Handler is null or empty.

post your code and we'll see how to help you.
Thanks

Comment: as I have mentioned, this error is very generic and has not been generated by the code. Any line on stack trace is not called on my page. Handler is null at System.Web.UI.ScriptComponentDescriptor.AddEvent(String name, String handler) which is called when ajaxtoolkit do the backend processing

Comment: Here is the code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_LJ7JfgiyasbjhVMEFHbWY4TGc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not clear when all the code in the call stack is in the .NET framework.  The error might be clear but the fix is not

Comment: @Mick I assume you have found this out since this question but .NET framework is open source (ish). So you can actually see what is happening in the .NET framework call stacks. Here's the site: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ there's also some options in Visual Studio to load the symbols and allow stepping through the framework code.